# Trouble in proof that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{2n+\sqrt n} = \frac {1}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Here is the analysis work I did to prepare for the proof. I have had all of one day experience with these proofs. Any guidance would be appreciated.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}  \frac{n}{2n+\sqrt n} = \frac{1}{2}$$

My professor says the inequality does not hold. Can I please have help locating my mistake?

Given $\epsilon > 0, \left|\frac{n}{2n+\sqrt n} -\frac{1}{2}\right |=\left|-\frac{2\sqrt n-1}{8n-2}\right|= \frac{2\sqrt n-1}{8n-2}\lt \frac{\sqrt n}{4n}=\frac{1}{4\sqrt n} \lt \epsilon$

Which implies $n > \frac{1}{16\epsilon^2}$.

Comment: some calculation error, I guess

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It should be
$$\left|\frac{n}{2n+\sqrt n} -\frac{1}{2}\right |=
\frac{\sqrt n}{2(2n+\sqrt n)}=\frac{1}{2(2\sqrt{n}+1)}<\frac{1}{4\sqrt{n}}<\epsilon$$

Comment: Yes, I see it now. Thank you!